# How to return http content in html by php request?

Tags: php, jquery

I have http address with some content (some advertisments). Let's say

http://servername/submit/rest/getHtmlAdvertisements/

I want to return this content on the html page. Let's say in

```
<div></div>
```

First I must connect to this `http://` a next I must display content in div (by jquery?). What can I do to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `jQuery` using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$( "div" ).load( "http://servername/submit/rest/getHtmlAdvertisements/" );
```

or by `PHP` using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
<?php
$someData = file_get_contents('http://servername/submit/rest/getHtmlAdvertisements/');
echo "<div>".$someData."</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways, you could use PHP [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the website content like:

```
<?php
    function curl_post($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $curl_response;
    }

    $content = curl_post('http://servername/submit/rest/getHtmlAdvertisements/');
?>
```

Now you would edit your `<div></div>` code to the following to display the content:

```
<div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
```

---

Or use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) like:

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('http://servername/submit/rest/getHtmlAdvertisements/');
    echo $content;
?>
```